# Django: Creating child users for a project to access data specific to company related to users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an Invoice project. A User can create an account, and once account is created he has to create a company profile.
The company profile table is linked to USER table with OnetoOnefield.
As a single user the application is working fine.
Now I would like to add give one function to User to create accounts of different users with different permissions.

I have googled but no achievable solution available.

How to create users linked with main user who created account and link them to a company profile?

After the comments, and answer I have updated my models as:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
                    ('service','service'),
                    ('product','product'),
    )
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    company_address=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Company_telephone=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_email=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_website=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    VAT=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    Service_Tax=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_PAN=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_bankdetails=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    invoice_type=models.CharField(max_length=250,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='service')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Company(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Organisation,related_name="company")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company
```

Now the problem is, suppose I have to create a Customer.
Currently what I am doing is,

Customer Model:

```
Customer_name=........    
user_company=......(request.user.company)
```

What should be done so that Users created by main users have same company as Main users.
With the method I am following, company ID changes for each user related to company.

Comment: Read up a little on Groups and Permissions. All your users can be part of the User table without any problem. All the created users can also have a relation to the same company as the user that created them. Only difference is that these users will have different set of permissions.

Comment: There isn't much to google, its views you need to write yourself. It sounds like fairly simple logic, what have you tried?

Comment: @ Resley and @ Sayse Updated the question with what I tried. Please answer.

Answer (score 1):

in first place, if you want multiple users connected to single company it's not going to work with OneToOneField.

I suggest to make a FK from user to company (assuming single user can access only one company) and if you want to make this first user have special permissions (so that the others will not be able to add users) you can make OneToOne field from company to user to point a managing user.

Also, personally I think assuming single user can access one company is a wrong solution. What about users that manager invoices for multiple companies (like account managers)? In that case a single m2m relation would do the trick and in the intermediary table you can put information about user's permissions.

Comment: I have updated the question with you solution. Please answer.